# Changing website to m. when on a mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Im pretty sure this question must have been asked before but I cant find anything. **I would like to create 2 versions of my website one where the mobile version is displayed in a subdomain such as m. and then the regular version for desktop.**

Ive searched SO, a [similar question is asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812320/how-to-run-mobile-version-of-a-website), but no direct answer is given rather it only talks about advantages and disadvantages, which at this stage does not concern me.

Ive searched the web and came across [a post from Mozilla where they mention the use of user-agent-detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Mobile/Separate_sites) but I cant for the life of me find a good example (perhaps im typing wrong queries)

If anyone can provide me with an **example / or a good link with how I can serve two different websites based on browser view-port size** it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your website comprised of static pages or are you using a backend as well? If so, which backend?

Comment: Using php for backend, why does it matter?

Comment: As a side remark, I want you to be aware of what responsive design is so that the choice for doing this is a well founded one.

Comment: Hey @Peter, the website has already been created, however it is only optimized for desktop! It will be quicker and easier for me to just redesign it for mobile and add it to subdomain compared to redesigning the whole site!

Comment: Hey @Timothy, I feel your pain :-) Good luck!

Comment: While this can be done on the client (with js), it is much more sensible to do it on the server. When done on the client, it first loads the entire desktop version before redirecting to the mobile version. If done on the server, it sends the mobile version immediately, saving loading time and data transferred. This would also allow you to use the same domain for both (if you wish), but sending different HTML to mobile devices

Comment: @Suppen very good point! For future readers of this question I would like to  point to this brilliant mobile detection script hosted on GitHub. https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/wiki/Code-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not using any framework, use this code :

```js
window.mobilecheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};



if (window.mobilecheck() == true) {
    window.location = "http://m." + window.location.host
}
```

Of course, this mobilecheck function was taken from this question
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Comment: WOW that is an insanely long check, i was thinking more in the line of an htaccess check or similar, but your answer is very helpful thank you

Answer (score -1):

In ASP.NET, you could implement it like this:

```
if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice == true)
{
     Response.Redirect("http://m.domain.com");
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged with javascript, and OP comments that backend is PHP